# Vertically align label with input

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am currently converting an old HTML form to not use tables. The label requires a fixed width, which I've achieved using an answer from this site. The current code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="form">
    <label for="field1">Name&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" id="field1" value="default name" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
input {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: *;
}
#field1 {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Currently, the label is vertically aligned at the top. How can I vertically align the label and field to the centre?

**Edit**: I'm getting a lot of answers to basically pad my label into the correct position via a specified number of pixels. I don't want to do that as it's basically hard-coding and not true vertical alignment to the middle.

Following some advice I've received here, I've cleaned up my code some. See the above edited code.

I've tried `vertical-align: middle;` in `label` but it doesn't work. Please note that the user's platform will be IE.

Comment: Do you need to align vertically center for whole page?

Comment: Try changing the line-height of the label

Comment: @Mani no. Just each line of label-field pair. I've found answers that work, but not once I include fixed widths in the label

Comment: can you try `padding: 4px;` for fieldHeading

Comment: Padding is basically hard-coding an absolute value, so no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I get this right, You want the `label` and the `input` to vertically center align W.R.T each other and not the page. For that, there are couple of ways.

## The Flexbox Way

If you want to use something new from the CSS world and be future ready, use flexbox. Example -

```css
.fieldHeading {
  width: 50px;
}
.fieldSpan {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#field1 {
  width: 150px;
}
/*flexbox approach.
* height and background added for clarity.
*/

#form {
  height: 100px;
  background: #bada55;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <label for="field1" class="fieldHeading">Name&nbsp;</label>
  <span class="fieldSpan"><input type="text" id="field1" value="default name" /></span>
</div>
```

## The `vertical-align` Way

This works well when you have both the `label` and the `input` on one line as `inline-block` elements. Example -

```css
.fieldHeading {
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.fieldSpan {
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#field1 {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <label for="field1" class="fieldHeading">Name&nbsp;</label>
  <span class="fieldSpan"><input type="text" id="field1" value="default name" /></span>
</div>
```

## The `height` & `line-height` Duo

This works well too but if your label is big and has the possibility of wrapping into multiple lines, it's gonna look terrible. Example -

```css
.fieldHeading {
  width: 50px;
}
.fieldSpan {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#field1 {
  width: 150px;
}

/*line-height and height be same for parent
* background added for clarity.
*/
#form {
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <label for="field1" class="fieldHeading">Name&nbsp;</label>
  <span class="fieldSpan"><input type="text" id="field1" value="default name" /></span>
</div>
```

I hope these help you not only in this problem but for all other vertical alignment problems.

Comment: Thanks! Your vertical alignment approach is already mentioned, though all mentioned variants didn't work for me. Your flexbox method however does. I suggest you highlight that solution at the top. +1 for implementing a true centre alignment, future-ready solution that works!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `line-height` or `margin-bottom` until you get satisfactory results.

**Example**

```
#form label {
    line-height:1.4;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

This will apply the selector to all labels under the form. If you want to be specific, you can use the specific css class like `.fieldHeading` instead of `#form label`.

Comment: How do I use these attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need like this?

```
<div id="form">
    <div class="valign">
        <label for="field1" class="fieldHeading">Name&nbsp;</label>
        <span class="fieldSpan"><input type="text" id="field1" value="default name" /></span>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.fieldHeading {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}
.fieldSpan {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: *;
}
#field1 {
    width: 150px;   
}

#form {display: table;height:100%;}

.valign {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

</style>
```

Comment: Is `display:table` good practice, considering that using `<table>` isn't? If it's acceptable, why?

Comment: @thegreatjedi - There is nothing wrong with using `display: table` for layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think, solution margin-bottom, use whatever px you want

```
.fieldHeading {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.fieldHeading {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#field1 { width: 150px; }
```

Let span be an inline type.

You don't really need the span for enclosing your input element.

Comment: Edited my code to reflect your advice. Your answer doesn't achieve what I'm trying to do however

Comment: I know you've found your answer, but still please have a look at this: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nain_1304/hema7uhp/1/)

Comment: Also flexbox is not supported on older browsers. See [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility). Take this into your notice.
I don't have enough reputation, otherwise would have replied on that answer! :)

Comment: Noted, thanks. We've control over the browsers & versions used by the users for this system so it'll be alright as long as it works for me.